# Integrating with respect to $y$ below $y=0$.

Tags: integration

For context, I'm currently studying integral calculus, so please keep that in mind!

I'm aware that if one is integrating with respect to $x$, for an area below $y=0$, we will get a negative answer. For example, $\int _{-3}^0\left(x\right)\:dx=-4.5$

If we were to take $\int _{-3}^0\sqrt{y^2}dy$ we get $4.5$. I'm a little confused as the area we are taking is below the $x$-axis, yet we are getting a positive result.
Thoughts?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{y^2} = |y|$, not just $y$

Comment: What does below the x-axis mean? The result is positive because the integrand is positive

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\not\equiv x$$.

Indeed, $\forall x\in[-3,0], \sqrt{x^2}=-x$, (for example $|-1|=1=-(-1)$)so you are actually evaluating $$\int_{-3}^0-x \ dx =-\int_{-3}^0 x\ dx=4.5$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you are integrating a function of $y$, you want to think of positive area as being **to the right of the $x$-axis** (rather than above the $y$-axis), and negative area as being **to the left of the $x$-axis** (rather than below the $y$-axis). As you can see in [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kyfzpmb59k), from $y=-3$ to $y=0$ the function is to the right of the $x$-axis, hence the area is positive.

Another way to think of this is that the variable of integration is irrelevant. You could swap it out for any other variable, e.g.,
$$\int_{-3}^0 \sqrt{y^2} \ dy = \int_{-3}^0 \sqrt{w^2 } \ dw = \int_{-3}^0 \sqrt{\xi^2} \ d \xi = \int_{-3}^0 \sqrt{x^2} \ dx.$$
In particular, taking the last expression and thinking about it as the area under the curve $y=\sqrt{x^2}$, we see that this function is above the $x$-axis and so the area will be positive.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is it true that for all integrals with respect to y, to the right of x=0 is always positive both above and below y=0, and negative on the left side of x=0?

Comment: Yes, the same way for an integral with respect to $x$ the area is positive above $y=0$ regardless of whether $x$ is positive/negative. (Note: this assumes the lower bound of the integral is less than the upper bound; if this is not the case then the sign is reversed.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{y^2}\geq0 $$ by definition, so it is positive not negativ for $y<0$.